# Rails controller not redirecting or rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I am trying to redirect to the a page after a form for email subscription is submitted. The subscriptions work fine but the page does not redirect.

This is what I have in the controller

```
class EmailapiController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

   def subscribe

   @list_id = "alistid"
   gb = Gibbon::API.new

   gb.lists.subscribe({                  
     :id => @list_id,
     :email => {:email => params[:email][:address]},
     :double_opt_in => false
     })

   flash[:success] = "Thank You for Subscribing"

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org" }
     #format.js
   end

  end 
end
```

My form looks like this

```
<%= form_tag('emailapi/subscribe', method: "post", id: "subscribe", remote: "true", class: "form-inline" ) do -%>
                    <%= email_field(:email, :address, {id: "email", placeholder: "Enter your email..."}) %>
                    <%= submit_tag("Notify Me", class: "submit-btn", id: "submit-btn" ) %>
<% end %>
```

and in routes.rb I have:

```
post 'emailapi/subscribe' => 'emailapi#subscribe'
```

Thanks

Comment: This is coming in in"format.js", are  you handling that in subscribe.js.erb?

Comment: Sorry i just copy pasted that for testing purposes from another redirect that was working. Without the for the format.js still the same issue. Ditto for using render or redirect_to instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a remote form, but not handling the js response. Create a view `subscribe.js.erb` and put this in it `window.location = "http://www.rubyonrails.org";`